# Jquery image gallery + fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, image-gallery

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to implement a fancybox effect into this slideshow image gallery. basically the idea would be that once clicked on big image or anywhere where you want, you would get let's say this first effect on fancybox

http://fancybox.net/

Here is the gallery

http://www.scriptiny.com/2008/12/javascript-slideshow/

Comment: Pero, Pero... You have already 'conglomerated' 4 unaccepted answers. How many more can you un-accept?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Sure it is possible. ;) The question is 'how many hours of work?'

The gallery has a div (imglink) over the image so it will be complicated to integrate the two things.

Comment: I tried to use this div of imglink for each of those images to be the link for that pop up fancybox...but just couldn0t achieve this. the thing that happens is that it is a normal hyperlink...it doesn not pop up in the same mirror...any advice?